# Prepend Coversheet PDF to all documents in folder Ruby Prawn

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a number of files in a Folder. I would like my code to loop over the files in the folder, convert them to a PDF and prepend a PDF coversheet to each of them. Keeping the original filename.

I have this so far, minus the prepend part.

```
require 'prawn'

file_array = Array.new
directory = "/Users/josh/Desktop/PDF"


Dir.foreach(directory) do |file|
    files = Dir.entries(directory)
    puts files

    for i in files
        Prawn::Document.generate()
    end
end
```

This doesn't create PDFs of all the files. How can I add this, and how can I prepend a PDF to them all?

Comment: what types of files do want to convert ? Does it txt ?

Comment: Document files, likely Word Docs

Comment: prawn is not a good choice for that. Actually this is not a conversion program. There are other gems that will do the job: https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby
https://github.com/ricn/libreconv